# Get a drive's partition table GUID or disk signature

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility

Given a drive's device node, how can the drive's disk signature (if it uses MBR partitioning) or it's partition table GUID (if it is partitioned with a GPT) be retrieved in a shell script or in Terminal?

It is preferable for the solution to work without root access though the solution will be incorporated into a script that will use root access. It is also preferable for the solution not to utilize any utilities dedicated to partitioning drives (meaning the likes of `fdisk` and `gdisk`, but NOT `diskutil`).

Comment: So diskutil would be fine? What have you tried to get the UUID already, how does it fail?

Comment: @nohillside It fails by not outputting a line that says what the GUID or disk signature is. I'm not looking for any kind UUID that is used only by OS X.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not looking for the GUID/UUIDs of partitions or filesystems.

Comment: @nohillside I'm not looking for the GUID/UUIDs of partitions or filesystems.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Your comment has disappeared.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the type of ID you are looking for?